# hiding text using "text-indent"

Tags: css, right-to-left, text-indent

I'm trying to hide some text inside an `<li>` element using CSS by setting `text-indent: -999px;`.
For some reason this doesn't work when I set the direction of the document to `"rtl"` (right to left - my site is in Hebrew).
When direction is "rtl" the text still shows...
Anyone knows why, and a way around this?

Comment: Note: I believe that that does not work in IE6. + http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/google_seo_and_using_css_to_hide_text/

Comment: you could you padding / overflow: hidden to hide your content, this works in every browser and any text direction. like this: ´width:0; height:0; padding: 400px 0 0 200px; overflow: hidden ´

Comment: if you don't get a good solution, you can always try other text hiding techniques :D http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Comment: Have you tried a positive `text-indent`?

Comment: i have tried a positive indent. it makes sense that it should work but it doesnt.

Answer (score 20):

Along with `text-indent: -9999px` try using `display: block;`. It solved for me.

Additionally, if you need the li elements to float horizontally (e.g. a horizontal menu), use `float: left;`.

Answer (score 12):

What about setting `direction:ltr` on the elements you're trying to give negative `text-indent`?

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/aJBnN/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/aJBnN/1/)

Comment: +1 that's the right answer - works and only changes a property that's irrelevant (since the text gets hidden)

Answer (score 4):

My problem was with text-align. In case you modify align mode of the element or parent element(s) wrapping it to left, you must give a negative index for text-indent. Otherwise you must give a positive value.

```
.case1{text-indent:-999px;text-align:left;overflow:hidden;display:block}
```

Otherwise

```
.case2{text-indent:999px;text-align:right;overflow:hidden;display:block}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting text-alignment to match the direction in which you are indenting text.

For example, if you use LTR and want to indent text negatively, besides adding display: block, you should also add left alignment.

Not sure for RTL, but seems logical you should indent it positively and use right alignment.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way is to make the text a transparent color:

color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

*Note: 
This bug still exists in firefox 12 (text-indent value is ignored on rtl)*

Answer (score 2):

```
color: transparent;
```

or

```
font-size:0px;
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this solution:

```
.hide_text { text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use line-height specifying a large value, say 100px for a 30px high container.

only works if your container is limited in size. you may have to specifically set height if it isn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `text-indent: -99px` is an old trick, which is not the optimal way to hide text. Why not use `visibility:hidden` instead?

Comment: Presumably this is an attempt to use a **background** image as content and provide real text for screen readers instead of using an `<img>` element with an `alt` attribute.

Comment: i cannot use visibility:hidden because i just need the text to go away. not the whole element in which the text is placed.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

text-align: right; works for me

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow hidden then it will work fine.

```css
div{
    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
 search
 <input type="text">
 </div>
```