# Center (proportional font) text in an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fonts

I would like to be able to center single lines of text within rectangular areas I can calculate. The one thing I have expected to do in 2D geometry on a canvas is to center something whose width is unknown to you.

I have heard as a workaround that you can create the text in an HTML container and then call jQuery's `width()` function, but I ?didn't correctly handle the momentary addition to the document's body? and got a width of 0.

If I have a single line of text, significantly shorter than would fill most of the width in a screen, how can I tell how wide it will be on a canvas at a font size I know?

Comment: Ḋon't set `display: none` for element before reading its width.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need a width of the text but just want to center text you can do

```
canvas_context.textBaseline = "middle";
canvas_context.textAlign = "center";
```

Which should put a text centered both vertically and horizontally.

See MDN's [textAlign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign) and [textBaseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline) for extra info with pictures

Answer (score 60):

You can do this by using [measureText](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-2dcontext-20110405/#dom-context-2d-measuretext)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;

ctx.fillStyle = "#003300";
ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';

var textString = "Hello look at me!!!",
    textWidth = ctx.measureText(textString ).width;


ctx.fillText(textString , (canvas.width/2) - (textWidth / 2), 100);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/a9zhc/2/)**

**[More elaborate demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/a9zhc/)**

Comment: @ChristosHayward ...except that it isn't accepted anymore.

Comment: @DavidsKanal well.. his comment was from 2012 ;)

Comment: @Loktar This feels like a time machine :D

Comment: how did u get 100 as the center of the text?

Comment: 100 is the heights center, canvas.height is set to 200 here, probably would have looked better if I made it,

`ctx.fillText(textString , (canvas.width/2) - (textWidth / 2), canvas.height/2);`

Answer (score 25):

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign) states in the `textAlign` description
that the alignment is based *on the x value* of the context's `fillText()` method. That is, the property does not center the text in the canvas horizontally; it centers the text around the given x coordinate. Similar applies for the `textBaseLine`.

So in order to center the text in both directions, we need to set those
two properties and position the text in the middle of the canvas.

```
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'; 
ctx.textAlign = 'center'; 

ctx.fillText('Game over', canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2);
```

Comment: Good comment ! the API don't say that the ctx.textAlign = 'center'  is centered from the x value of ctx.fillText('text', x, y) ...  hours of research ...

Comment: Extremely important nuance that is not documented well.

Answer (score 3):

For centering horizontally we use `ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'; ctx.textAlign = 'center';`. But to center vertically we need to use `ctx.measureText`.

`(actualBoundingBoxAscent - actualBoundingBoxDescent) / 2` is important, because for different fonts text can be differently aligned vertically.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696631/canvas-drawings-like-lines-are-blurry/59143499#59143499
function setCanvas(canvas, w, h) {
    canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
    const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.width = w * scale;
    canvas.height = h * scale;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
}

const width = 160;
const height = 160;
const fontSize = 100;
const text = 'A';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

setCanvas(canvas, width, height); 

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.font = `${fontSize}px sans-serif`;
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
let { actualBoundingBoxAscent, actualBoundingBoxDescent } = ctx.measureText(text);
ctx.fillText(text, width / 2, height / 2 + (actualBoundingBoxAscent - actualBoundingBoxDescent) / 2);
```

```css
canvas{
  outline: 1px black solid
 }
```

```html
<canvas><canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ctx.textAlign = "center";** to align item to center

```
var canva = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx.textAlign = "center"; // To Align Center
ctx.font = "40px Arial"; // To change font size and type
ctx.fillStyle = '#313439'; // To give font 
ctx.fillText("Text Center", 150 ,80);
```

Comment: how did u determine "80" to be the center of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering around how to properly align the height as well, since `measureText()` does not return the height (!).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const centered = (text, size) => {
  ctx.font = size + 'px monospace';
  let s = ctx.measureText(text).width;
  ctx.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2 - s / 2, canvas.height / 2 + size / 4);
}  
    
/* Just for the demo, really! 
 * Please don't do this!
 * Use proper animation frames requests
 * and clear timeout(s)!!! */
[["is", 40], ["able",45], ["<-- to -->",50], ["FLEX", 55], [" SMOOTH!", 58], ["FLEX!!", 62], ["FLEX!!!", 63] ].forEach((e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    centered(e[0], e[1])
  }, e[1]*100)
})

// Intro test
centered("CANFLEX", 50)
```

```css
canvas{
  outline: 1px black solid
 }
```

```html
<canvas><canvas>
```

Comment: how did u determine "size" over 4 specifically?

Comment: For the How, likely trial error, and for the Why i can't tell precisely. However this might be a good separate question.

Answer (score -6):

What you do is render your text off-screen using a negative text-indent, then grab the size.

```
text-indent: -9999px
```

See: [hiding text using "text-indent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794656/hiding-text-using-text-indent)

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with the question being asked. He's looking to get the size so he can center them within canvas.

Comment: In think his answer is related on the _workaround_ JonathanHayward mentioned, but asking the text's width directly to the canvas (as in your answer) is better (and more reliable) in this case.

Comment: Loktar, read the question "I didn't correctly handle the momentary addition to the document's body and got a width of 0." -- That's because you can't measure hidden content. The alternative is to make it visible but OFF SCREEN so the user doesn't see it, then measure it.