# HTML5: Center text within rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to show the `id` of the rectangle in the center of it.

Here is my model:

```
var rects = [
    [a,  20, w, h, 'Day of the week'],
    [a, 130, w, h, 'Final'],
    [a, 240, w, h, 'Direction'],
    [a, 350, w, h, 'GoSS'],
    [a, 460, w, h, 'Cyber'],
    [a, 570, w, h, 'Ultumate77'],
    [a, 680, w, h, 'Ami'],
    [a, 790, w, h, 'TestFasePartTwo'],
    [a, 900, w, h, 'HerHavzunDibiAyni']
];
```

Here an external link to the code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/c3538o0v/2/

I tried overlaying but that's not what I want. The question is what do I have to use to automatically put it in the center without going out the rectanglecenter the text within the rectangle?

PS: I have deleted the overlay code.

### Code

```js
var mydata = [{
  "name": "Name: Name Day of the Week",
  "version": "Version: 1.0.0",
  "LocalTimeZone": "Local Time Zone: CET",
  "country": "Country: NLD",
  "input": "Input: DateTime (Format see properties)<br>\n\
Current Date Time = System Date Time <br>\n\
Node Enabled = Y/N (Default Yes) <br>\n\
Language = EN (Default EN)",
  "properties": "Properties: DateTime Format = ISO 8601 (Default)<br> \n\
Current Date Time = System Date Time<br>\n\
CountryArea = +31 (NLD)<br>\n\
Time Zone = CET (Depends on Country/Area)<br>\n\
Daylight Saving = Y/N<br>\n\
DST Starts = (Depends on Country/Area)<br>\n\
DST Ends = (Depends on Country/Area)"

}, {
  "name": "Final",
  "text": "1001",
  "version": "1.2",
  "country": "NL"

}, {
  "name": "Direction",
  "text": "LucBen",
  "version": "1.5.8",
  "country": "CN"

}, {
  "name": "GoSS",
  "text": "55",
  "version": "5",
  "country": "BE"

}, {
  "name": "Cyber",
  "text": "KroOn",
  "version": "3.2.11",
  "country": "FR"

}, {
  "name": "Ultumate77",
  "text": "Nei",
  "version": "22",
  "country": "D"

}, {
  "name": "Ami",
  "text": "Da",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "country": "VS"

}, {
  "name": "TestFasePartTwo-One",
  "text": "99ft22",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "country": "CH"

}, {
  "name": "HerHavzunDibiAyni",
  "text": "GitteBag",
  "version": "1",
  "country": "TR"

}, {
  "name": "SPYH",
  "text": "500",
  "version": "1.1.1.1",
  "country": "BeneluxS"

}];

var a = 20;
var w = 150;
var h = 100;
var canvas = $('#NodeList').get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = 0;

var rects = [
  [a, 20, w, h, 'Day of the week'],
  [a, 130, w, h, 'Final'],
  [a, 240, w, h, 'Direction'],
  [a, 350, w, h, 'GoSS'],
  [a, 460, w, h, 'Cyber'],
  [a, 570, w, h, 'Ultumate77'],
  [a, 680, w, h, 'Ami'],
  [a, 790, w, h, 'TestFasePartTwo'],
  [a, 900, w, h, 'HerHavzunDibiAyni']
];

for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
  canvas.height = canvas.height + 110;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // rectangles opnieuw tekenen
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    ctx.fillRect(rects[j][0],
                 rects[j][1],
                 rects[j][2],
                 rects[j][3]);
  }

  ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
               rects[i][1],
               rects[i][2],
               rects[i][3]);
}

$('#NodeList').click(function(e) {
  var x = e.offsetX,
      y = e.offsetY;

  for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    if (x > rects[i][0] && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] &&
        y > rects[i][1] && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('NodeDisplay');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

      $(".een").empty().append(mydata[i].name + '<br> ' + mydata[i].version + (mydata[i].LocalTimeZone ? '<br> ' + mydata[i].LocalTimeZone : "") + '<br> ' + mydata[i].country);

      $(".twee").empty().append(mydata[i].input);

      $(".vier").empty().append(mydata[i].properties);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
b {
  margin-left: 75px;
}
#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
.scrollbar {
  height: 1050px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
.content {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#Display {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 248px;
}
.beeld {
  max-height: 301px;
  min-height: 301px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 134px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#NodeDisplay {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 133px;
}
#canvas-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 380px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 435px;
}
#canvas-wrap canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0
}
.een {
  height: 120px;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.twee {
  height: 120px;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.drie {
  max-height: 70px;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.vier {
  max-height: 70px;
  min-height: 145px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Nodes</b>
<br>
<div class="scrollbar">
  <div class="content">
    <canvas id="NodeList" width="200" height="300">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Display" id="Display">
  <canvas id="NodeDisplay" width="300" height="300" style="border:2px solid black;"></canvas>
  <div id="overlayBeeld"></div>
  <div class="beeld" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
<div id="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas width="600" height="600" style="border:2px solid black;"></canvas>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div class="een" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
  <div class="twee" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
  <div class="drie" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
  <div class="vier" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which rectangle you mean ??...the node ones in your fiddle?which is the id of rect??

Comment: Not sure if that's just me, but such fiddle seems to be quite heavy, even resizing the inner iframes is creating some strange delays.

Comment: @AkshayJ 
1st node Day of the week
2nd node Final
3rd node Direction
etc etc

Comment: I try to get it into nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/c3538o0v/3/)):

```
var rects = [
    [a, 20, w, h, 'Day of the week'],
    [a, 130, w, h, 'Final'],
    [a, 240, w, h, 'Direction'],
    [a, 350, w, h, 'GoSS'],
    [a, 460, w, h, 'Cyber'],
    [a, 570, w, h, 'Ultumate77'],
    [a, 680, w, h, 'Ami'],
    [a, 790, w, h, 'TestFasePartTwo'],
    [a, 900, w, h, 'HerHavzunDibiAyni']
];

canvas.height = 110 * rects.length;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.textAlign="center";
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
        rects[i][1],
        rects[i][2],
        rects[i][3]);
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillText(rects[i][4], rects[i][0]+rects[i][2]/2, rects[i][1]+rects[i][3]/2);
}
```

Your code had several bugs:

1. The size of the canvas changed all the time
2. You cleared the canvas in the outer loop, erasing all the rects that you had rendered so far

New stuff: Setting the text alignment to center it around a point (in this case, the center of he rectangle).

After that, I just had to set the text color to `black` and call

```
ctx.fillText(rects[i][4], rects[i][0]+rects[i][2]/2, rects[i][1]+rects[i][3]/2);
```

Related:

- [Center (proportional font) text in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771310/center-proportional-font-text-in-an-html5-canvas)

Comment: And is it possible that when i have a long text that it stays in it  ??

exameple if i change Day of the week in to Day of the weeksjhfdksjdfhksjhfdsd  its out the rectangle ?

And thnx you for your help and time

Comment: You can either have complex text layout by using `div` plus CSS (without `canvas`) or simple/manual text layout + `canvas`. See also: https://gist.github.com/dsamarin/1148888

Comment: 1+ for also adding the `ctx.textBaseline='middle';` so that it also adjusts for different font sizes. If you want to keep it inside the rectangle also for long strings you can check its total width with `ctx.measureText(myText).width`and either reduce the font size until it fits or wrap text (see here for wrapping text http://www.niddro.com/post/wrap-text-in-canvas-with-javascript)