# Vertically Centering Text In Canvas Based on Font Size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do you vertically align text in canvas, based on the font size assigned?  For instance, I have a rectangle with the height of 100px, and the variable `textSize`.  My goal is to always vertically center the text inside of this specific rectangle.

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8op5gv5/3/)

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var textSize = 40;

function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 100);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Text
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = textSize + "px 'Oswald'";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.textBaseline="middle";
    ctx.fillText("Hello, World", 100, (100 - textSize)/2);
    ctx.restore();
}

window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771310/center-proportional-font-text-in-an-html5-canvas) answer might help

The canvas's context has a [measureText](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-2dcontext-20110405/#dom-context-2d-measuretext) function which you can use.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the right answer.  Especially considering different typefaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas

Comment: @Beep. While your link is helpful, please do not post link-only answers -- even when the links are to Stackoverflow itself. Instead, post your link as a comment to the original question and not as an answer. This helps us avoid duplicate Q&A on Stackoverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `textBaseline= "middle"` Why you are calculating the y coordinate considering textSize? 
Probably

```
ctx.fillText("Hello, World", 100, 50);
```

This will do the job for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a calculation that works if the `textSize` variable changes.  Perhaps aligning to top or bottom would make things easier, though?